# How to set user_actions permission for Facebook App?

Tags: facebook

We are building a WebApp and need:

- user_actions.music
- user_actions.video

permissions enabled.

Our app is still in sandbox mode (only developer access).
But I cannot see these above permissions in **"App Center Permissions"** dialog box.

[image]

I have also tried manually typing these permissions but that did not work out.

How do I set these permission requests for my Facebook App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the scope parameter in the login process in you application itself. It depends how you implement your app, the language etc.

For example, if you use the login button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="user_actions.music,user_actions.video">
</fb:login-button>
```

Or if you built a manual flow:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&scope=user_actions.music,user_actions.video&response_type=code%20token
```

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#login